# Conditional update of several fields

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm new with rethinkdb, I'm trying to write an update query preferred upsert which will set values to several fields if they don't exist or their values is less than the new value I want to set. Below is the way I did it with mongodb

```
 collection.updateOne(new BasicDBObject(BookKeeperEvent.tenantPropertyName, bookKeeper.getTenantId()).append(BookKeeperEvent.timeLayerPropertyName, bookKeeper.getTimeLayer()),
            new BasicDBObject("$max", new BasicDBObject(BookKeeperEvent.latestFullDataPropertyName, bookKeeper.getLatestFullData())
                    .append(BookKeeperEvent.latestRawDataPropertyName, bookKeeper.getLatestRawData())
                    .append(BookKeeperEvent.latestHealthPropertyName, bookKeeper.getLatestHealth())
                    .append(BookKeeperEvent.lastUpdatePropertyName, bookKeeper.getLastUpdate())
                    .append(BookKeeperEvent.firstFullDataPropertyName, bookKeeper.getFirstFullData()))
                    .append("$setOnInsert", new BasicDBObject(BookKeeperEvent.tenantPropertyName, bookKeeper.getTenantId()).append(BookKeeperEvent.timeLayerPropertyName, bookKeeper.getTimeLayer())),
            new UpdateOptions().upsert(true))
```

This code set tenantId and timeLayer only if they are null, and for the other fields only if they are null or the value is less than the value I set in the query.
Is there a way to do the same thing in rethinkdb? and how?

Comment: I think the following query is equivalent to what I did in mongo but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query is equivalent to what I did in mongo but it fails.

```
r.table('book_keeper').filter({tenantId: '123', timeLayer: 4}).coerceTo('array').do(function (matches) {
```

return r.branch(
    matches.isEmpty(),
    r.table('book_keeper').insert({tenantId: '123', timeLayer: 4, latestRawData: 100, id: 4}),
    r.table('book_keeper').get(4).update(function (doc) {
      return r.branch(
      doc.not(doc.hasFields('firstFullData')).or(doc('firstFullData').lt(100)),
        {firstFullData : 100},
      null)
    }
    ))
})

The excption is:

```
e: Expected 1 argument but found 2 in:
r.table("book_keeper").filter({"tenantId": "123", "timeLayer": 4}).coerceTo("array").do(function(var_193) { return r.branch(var_193.isEmpty(), r.table("book_keeper").insert({"tenantId": "123", "timeLayer": 4, "latestRawData": 100, "id": 4}), r.table("book_keeper").get(4).update(function(var_194) { return r.branch(var_194.not(var_194.hasFields("firstFullData")).or(var_194("firstFullData").lt(100)), {"firstFullData": 100}, null); })); })
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Daniela